# MongoDB atlas trigger getting error: TypeError: Cannot access member 'db' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I am a newbie trying MongoDB-atlas free tier. I have a cluster named - "mongoCluster. Under it, I have a database - "testdb" and under it, have a collection - "testcollection". This collection has documents. The inserts and read from my java app are working fine.

Now I am trying to create a new scheduled trigger in MongoDB atlas. But as I am running the following two lines, I am getting the following error. Same holds true for any other mongo query like delete, update and insert.

**Code:**

```
exports = function() {
  
    const collection=context.services.get("mongoCluster").db("testdb").collection("testcollection");
    collection.insertOne({"a": "b"});
   // const doc = collection.findOne();

};
```

**Error:**

```
> ran on Mon Nov 16 2020 18:52:52 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
> took 272.591178ms
> error: 
TypeError: Cannot access member 'db' of undefined
> trace: 
TypeError: Cannot access member 'db' of undefined
    at exports (function.js:24:24)
    at apply (<native code>)
    at function_wrapper.js:3:1
    at <anonymous>:8:1
```

Looking at the error, either the service name is incorrect ("undefined error") OR I am missing some permissions on the service/database/collection ("anonymous:8:1 error").

I read somewhere in the MongoDB documentation, the service name = cluster name. Is there a way to see whats my service name? Have tried service name in lower case too, but no luck. Also tried same with fully qualified service name - "mongocluster.qeat9.mongodb.net", same error.

Or it is something else I am missing? Can someone please help here?

**EDIT 1:**

Adding a screenshot of the trigger function text which has the sample commented code. See the second line from the bottom which shows the syntax I have been using.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: hi @Minsky - Thanks for looking at it. When we create a new function in a trigger, there comes a commented sample function code. Thats where I picked this example from and looked at several other posts doing the same thing. it says - "    Note: In Atlas Triggers, the service name is defaulted to the cluster name." . I am putting the sample code provided in my next comment.

Comment: @Minsky - Here is the commented sample code mongodb atlas publishes in the function creation section. My understanding is that this trigger runs in my database and hence should have all the access it needs. But definitely I am wrong somewhere.

   // Access a mongodb service:
   // const collection = context.services.get(<SERVICE_NAME>).db("db_name").collection("coll_name");
  //  const doc = collection.findOne({ name: "mongodb" });

Comment: @Minsky - To add, I also tried the full service name - "mongocluster.qeat9.mongodb.net", but same error I am getting.

Comment: @Minsky - Let me add a screenshot of it in my post. Its inside a text box once I login, so can't access via link. Give me a moment.

Comment: don't worry found it

Comment: @Minsky - Just added the screenshot. Did not see your comment that you found it earlier.

Comment: @Anurag Were you able to resolve the issue? I am facing the exact same problem.

Comment: @pagalpanda - No I was not able to. I gave up :).

Answer (score 10):

I linked an example of the page where you should be able to find your linked clusters ("Linked Data Sources" in the side-nav). Then you can use that service name in `context.services.get("my-svc")...`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Haley for looking at it. I do not have a realm application and hence i do not see this view which you shared, at all. When I click on realm tab on top bar, I see an option to create a new realm application. I am simply trying to create a trigger under the "atlas" tab on the top bar. Do I need to use a Realm application to be able to run a trigger?

Comment: @Anurag I believe creating a Trigger creates a Realm App

Answer (score 4):

Before you run the trigger, **check whether you linked the cluster in the form above the function**.
[image: click the link button after you select the cluster]

*(I spent hours solving this so excuse the red colour and bold font.)*

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure what trigger you want to use. refer [docs: mongodb trigger-types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/trigger-types/)

Then, you have to link the data source (click on the button)
[image: Link the data source image]

After that, you have to use the **cluster name** instead of "mongodb-atlas" as said in the comments of a **Scheduled Trigger**
[image: See comments here]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to use the actual cluster name instead of the `mongodb-atlas`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default code provided from Atlas within the Function Editor examine the following for the wrong serviceName variable

```
// Find the name of the MongoDB service you want to use (see "Linked Data Sources" tab)
  var serviceName = "mongodb_atlas";
```

The serviceName variable should have a hyphen not an underscore.

```
// Find the name of the MongoDB service you want to use (see "Linked Data Sources" tab)
  var serviceName = "mongodb-atlas";
```