# MongoDB Atlas scheduled trigger service returning undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I’m trying to create a scheduled trigger to clear a collection weekly, but I am unable to get the service…
`const collection = context.services.get('mongodb-atlas');` is returning undefined when I log it to console, and when I try and using it, it just says `Cannot access member ‘db’ of undefined`. I’ve also tried setting the service name to `Cluster0` and `mongodb-datalake`, neither of which worked.

If someone could lend a hand on what I’m doing wrong and how I’m meant to do this, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70308971/717267

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB atlas trigger getting error: TypeError: Cannot access member 'db' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868729/mongodb-atlas-trigger-getting-error-typeerror-cannot-access-member-db-of-und)

Answer (score -3):

You need the following syntax to get to your collection:

```
const collection = context.services.get(<SERVICE_NAME>).db("db_name").collection("coll_name");
```

`SERVICE_NAME` you can find from here:

1. Go into `Realm` tab
2. In the left navigation, click on `Linked Data Sources`
3. Copy the `Realm Service Name`